# Why must Jmeter HTTP Sampler Settings be set to HTTPClient3.1 or Java (not HTTPClient4) when using client certificates through Firefox?

Tags: ssl, iis, jmeter

I have a pretty standard JMeter setup - Version r1743807 on Windows7. Firefox is configured correctly and connects to the JMeter Proxy without issue - I can use the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to record a session without issue.

However when I attempt to connect to a site which requires a client certificate, I get a 403.7 error (the site is IIS hosted) if I use anything other than HTTPClient3.1 or Java for the HTTP Sampler Settings Type in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

Comment: I am experiencing the same sort of issue when specifying a client certificate and setting the HTTP Request Defaults  config element's Implementation to HttpClient4.

If I use HttpClient3.1 or Java then I get asked for the certificate's password when I first play the script, but I do not get a prompt for the certificate's password and I get "403 Forbidden" response codes if I use HttpClient4. The website I am making requests to requires a valid client certificate to access it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not experience any problems with HTTPClient4 client implementation, moreover it is recommended to use HTTPClient4 instead of HTTPClient3.1. See [HTTP Request Sampler documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) for details.

[image: HTTPClient 4]

Client certificate is configured via JMeter *system.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder) like:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=certificate.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=s3cr3t
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
```

More information on JMeter keystore creation and configuration: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)